# Passing game logic in JavaFX?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

i'm currently developing a table RPG game in Java. I developed the game logic and the connections (socket/RMI). Now the game works with CLI. I want to implement the GUI with JavaFX and sceneBuilder. I designed all the scenes and started writing the controllers. My question is: how can I pass the logic of my game to the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather conceptual, hence the conceptual answer.

**OO approach.** As long as the model (game logic) is well separated from the view (CLI / GUI), it shouldn't be much of an issue. Assuming you have some sort of `Game` / `GameLogic` class, all you need is to pass its instance to the relevant controller. You presumably have one controller per one FXML view. When you load your scenes you can use [setControllerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) to inform `FXMLLoader` about how your controller needs to be created. With this insight in mind, you can attempt the following:

```
MainGameController(Game game) {
    this.game = game; // now your controller has an instance of your game logic
}
```

Then, where you load your view (likely to be in `Application` subclass):

```
FXMLLoader loader = ...
Game game = ...

loader.setControllerFactory(t -> new MainGameController(game));
```

If your game logic is split into several parts and each can have its own view, simply adopt the same instantiation of your controllers.

**Pragmatic approach.** Say you don't want to do a significant amount of wiring behind the scenes. In that case you could create a single point of access across your whole game, in essence similar to the Singleton pattern. If your game has other services on top of game logic, e.g. `AudioPlayer`, `AssetLoader`, this approach might actually be more beneficial.

```
class GameApplication {

    static Game game; // + getters / setters
    static AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
    ...
}
```

Then in your `MainGameController` (or any other):

```
// called automatically by FXMLLoader
public void initialize() {
    this.game = GameApplication.getGame();
}
```